# Is it possible to serialize a dynamic object graph to xml with specific xml namespaces (xmlns)?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, serialization, dynamic, xml-namespaces

I have a funky scenario that, thanks to our use of .NET 4 and C# 4, seemed to be in the bag. As it turns out, the solution is more complex, and possibly non-existent outside of some completely custom solution.

In a nutshell, I need to serialize a dynamic object that has a set of fixed, required properties, and an arbitrary set of optional properties. The root element must include a custom xml namespace in the xmlns attribute, and it may be necessary for some of the child objects to use different xml namespaces. Our first approach was to derive a custom class from `DynamicObject`. This allowed us to add an `XmlRootAttribute` and specify a namespace. Barring the complication of defining custom namespaces on dynamic properties, even this simple approach did not seem to work. The `XmlSerializer`, despite being passed a `dynamic` variable as the object to serialize, simply serializes the hard-coded properties, and ignores any dynamic aspects of the object.

We have been using JsonFx 2.0 for a while, and decided to give that a try. With some careful improvements to our `DynamicObject` derivative, we were able to get JsonFx 2.0 to serialize all of the necessary content, however it refuses to serialize any xmlns attributes.

Is there some way to serialize a partially dynamic object to xml and include specific namespaces? Or is this simply a case of having to define an arbitrarily complex object graph, choosing the graph that fits the specific needs as dynamically derived at runtime?

Seems the xml serialization story for .NET 4 is rather lax when it comes to serializing dynamic objects.

Comment: Have you figured out a different solution to this problem? If so, it would be nice if you posted it here. :-)

Comment: you can try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951521/web-api-dynamic-to-xml-serialization/19085236#19085236

Answer (score 2):

The `XmlSerializer` will poke at your `IXmlSerializable` implementation (if you implement it) before doing any of the reflection magic it needs to find `[XmlElement]` and its crazy siblings. Just implement `IXmlSerializable` alongside `DynamicObject` and you should be able to dynamically both read and write whatever XML you please.

Comment: Aye, thanks for the tip. I am hoping to avoid having to do any kind of manual XML serialization, as that can get very complex and very messy very fast.