# Web API - Dynamic to XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a Web API web service that is returning dynamically constructed property bag. Is there any working serializer or a way how to serialize dynamic to XML? I tried to look for any good suggestions but haven't found anything usable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We solved it by creating a custom XML formatter.

This isn't an ideal solution but it works.

In the `Global.asax`

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new CustomXmlFormatter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters
    .Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Create a new class called `CustomXmlFormatter`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EMP.WebServices.api.Formatters
{
    public class CustomXmlFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public CustomXmlFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            if (type == (Type)null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value,
            Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content,
            System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

                        var xml = JsonConvert
                            .DeserializeXmlNode("{\"Root\":" + json + "}", "");

                        xml.Save(writeStream);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a fantastic answer. This guarantees that if you're also using the Newtonsoft Json converter, you'll always wind up with the same data being output by both formats - without having to mark up all of your models.

Comment: I would suggest adding a JsonMediaTypeFormatter parameter to CustomXmlFormatter. Then when you call SerializeObject, pass in the JsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings. This will make sure you use the same settings to create both JSON and XML.

Comment: For me, this is a really elegant solution to the very issue that @Brian mentions above: I wanted my JSON settings customizations to carry over to the XML media type; thanks for sharing this approach, @Jakub! FWIW, I edited the answer with the implementation I ultimately ended up with that accounts for "array" types and accounts for the ability to deserialize XML.

Comment: I like the XML this produces better than the built in formatter.  However, I found the operation to be extremely fast and the System.Xml.XmlDocument to be just a little more than trivial to use in async code.  I didn't use Task.Factory.StartNew to queue this work, but instead derived from BufferedMediaTypeFormatter and found no  performance difference under load and didn't create a Task for the sake of complying with the method signature.