# WebAPI Remove z:anyType Element from XML Results

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an interface as follows

```
public interface IResponse
{
    IResponse GetSuccessResponse();
    IResponse GetErrorResponse();
}
```

I then have various classes that implement logic as follows

```
[KnownType(typeof(DefaultResponse))]
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class DefaultResponse : IResponse
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public IResponse GetSuccessResponse()
    {
        return new DefaultResponse()
        {
            Status = "Accept",
            Info = "Success"
        };
    }

    public IResponse GetErrorResponse()
    {
        return new DefaultResponse()
        {
            Status = "Reject",
            Info = "Fail"
        };
    }
}
```

When returning a response in my WebAPI, I am using a factory pattern to get the IResponse type needed, and calling IResponse.GetErrorResponse. The problem is this always generates XML like the following

```
<z:anyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="" i:type="DefaultResponse" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <Status>Reject</Status>
    <Info>Fail</Info>
</z:anyType>
```

Is there any way to get rid of the z:anyType element and replace it with the actual class name. It works if I use the class directly, but not with the interface involved.

I am creating the response using the following type of code:

```
return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, responseType.GetErrorResponse());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing this up a bit to instead use a custom serializer like the following answer
[Web API - Dynamic to XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951521/web-api-dynamic-to-xml-serialization)

This provided me with the greatest flexibility as it allows you to output exactly what the class looks like in XML without any of the attributes on the class